# Convert cell arrays into single array

Tags: mysql, sql, matlab

Getting started with Matlab and mySQL, as a result for my query I get this type of array:

```
my_result =

  5×1 cell array

    {'a'}
    {'b'}
    {'c'}
    {'d'}
    {'e'}
```

I'd like to get a simple array like this:

```
[a, b, c, d, e]
```

Here's my code:

```
mysql( 'open', 'my_database', 'usr','passw' )

query = fileread('query1.sql');           
query = sprintf(query)

my_result = mysql(query);
```

And my attempts at getting a simple array:

```
my_array = []
for i=1:length(my_result)
   my_array = [my_array, my_result{i}];
end


>> my_array

my_array =

    'abcde'

>> cell2mat(my_result)
Error using cat
Dimensions of arrays being concatenated are not consistent.

Error in cell2mat (line 83)
            m{n} = cat(1,c{:,n});
```

Is there a way to either get the correct format in the first place, or easily convert it properly? Thank you

Comment: MySQL doesn't support arrays, so your question is rather unclear.

Answer (score 2):

just use the cell2mat built-in function

```
a{1} =  'a' 
a{2} =  'b' 
a{3} =  'c' 
a{4} =  'd' 
a{5} =  'e' 


a =

  5×1 cell array

    {'a'}
    {'b'}
    {'c'}
    {'d'}
    {'e'}


cell2mat(a)

ans =

  5×1 char array

    'a'
    'b'
    'c'
    'd'
    'e'
```

Comment: Oh actually I tried that one, I'll update my post

Comment: then you did get a 5x1 array of chars... what is the problem?

Comment: from your edit you have already a char array (in the original question you started from a cell array)  , is what you want is just some different way that this info is visualized? because that's how char type letters are presented.